# Interpolate an attribute value along poyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a river as polyline with several vertices. Also I have stage and bottom level information for the start and the end point of the river. How can I interpolate the value for stage and bottom level along this line for the vertices in between the start and endpoints?

I am working with QGIS.

Comment: If you wish to ask about Python, then please include a code snippet that illustrates what you've tried and where you're stuck.  If you wish to ask about ArcGIS Desktop then do that in a separate question and specify whether you are using its ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application.